# How to solve Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' in django

Tags: django

This the Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: ipaddressHere/admin/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 48, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 141, in get_host
    if domain and validate_host(domain, allowed_hosts):
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 691, in validate_host
    return any(pattern == '*' or is_same_domain(host, pattern) for pattern in allowed_hosts)
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 691, in <genexpr>
    return any(pattern == '*' or is_same_domain(host, pattern) for pattern in allowed_hosts)
  File "C:\Users\siddh\.virtualenvs\backend-8q1GYrV6\lib\site-packages\django\utils\http.py", line 292, in is_same_domain
    pattern = pattern.lower()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I dont face this error when I comment ALLOWED_HOSTS so I feel it has to do something with it. Everything was working fine before I did not change anything.
This is how my allowed host looks like

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
     and other ip adresses in same format
],
```

Comment: "and other ip adresses in same format", well  a sample of that would be helpful... Please see how to write a [mre].

Comment: Can you try without the brackets? `ALLOWED_HOSTS = '127.0.0.1','127.0.0.1','etc'`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am not sure what you mean by a sample. As in the code i have provided '127.0.0.1' others are same as that. They are strings just like ''127.0.0.1''.

Comment: @KarolosK. Well that worked not sure why docs say that allowed host is a list of string. 'A list of strings representing the host/domain names......'

Comment: @Sid looking at the answer below that is because of the extra comma you had.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yup that worked and so did karolos comment but I am not sure why ( about why karolos' method works)

Comment: @Sid Karolos' method works because '127.0.0.1','127.0.0.1','etc' will create a tuple. The `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should simply be an iterable containing strings so a tuple with strings will also work.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sounds right, instead of 'list', docs should then say 'iterables' maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
     and other ip adresses in same format
],
```

It needs to be

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
     and other ip adresses in same format
]
```

(Notice there isn't a comma at the end)

Comment: Thank you that worked tho not sure how did that comma reached there it was working before. I might have added it accidentally before closing the editor last time I was working.